# Open DataReader error with TPL async calls to DAL object

Tags: c#, .net, linq, task-parallel-library

I'm using TPL to make async calls to a method in my DAL which fetches data from the backend. This works fine but occasionally an `EntityCommandExecutionException` exception is thrown with

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which
>   must be closed first.

message.

Obviously, this is caused by one thread trying to access the method of the same instance of a DAL object that another thread is still using so I resolved this by instantiating that DAL object every time a call is made and this solves the problem but I'm wondering if there is a way to solve this problem without having to instantiate the DAL object every time a call is made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Give every thread a DAL instance
2. Make calls to the DAL thread-safe (with `lock`).

Comment: I was already doing 1, 2 works as well but the DAL object in question has a small memory footpring so I'll stick to what I've been doing already...

Comment: It's not just the DAL. It also caches records... I would favour 2)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [ThreadStatic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx) attribute on your DAL object.

This will avoid the need for locks.

Comment: This was promising but I was still getting same error even after I made both my entities and my IList `ThreadStatic` at the same line where I was querying the db (myList = context.myEnt....ToList()) ... maybe I was doing something wrong...

Comment: Glad I learned about that attribute though, I'm sure it will come in handy some time... +1

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [ThreadLocal(T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243.aspx) which was introduced to .NET4.0. Though you could use ThreadStatic attribute, there are some limitations.

1. Thread­Sta­tic attribute does not work with instance fields.
2. Field always start with the default value.

On the contrary, ThreadLocal enables to initialize non-static filed or local variable, and to initialize the field with a non-default value, which is lazily evaluated.

Check the following example.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int index = 0;
    var threadString = new ThreadLocal<string>(() => (index++).ToString());
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)new Thread(o => Console.WriteLine(threadString)).Start();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your pointer to this useful new feature in .NET 4... +1